# How styles in ui binder gets reflected in deployed application

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I have seen some stylesheets are injected in hosted html page which has href value null. Are those coming from styles declared in ui.xml file? How the styles declared in ui.xml files get reflected in gwt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ui:style>` in UiBinder are internally known as *implicit `CssResource`*: `<ui:style>`, `<ui:image>` and `<ui:data>` generate implicit resources in an implicit `ClientBundle`. UiBinder automatically calls `ensureInjected()` on the implicit `CssResource`s (generated by `<ui:style>`)

Comment: It might be worth adding that each of those implicit `CssResource`s are separate beings/"namespaces" and as such the style `.alert` defined in one of them will be a different one then the `.alert` style defined in a different UiBinder template. They each will get obfuscated to a different name - so that same-named styles from different UiBinder templates wouldn't collide with each other.